# ModelMapper mapear entidades

Tags: java, spring-boot

Trabajo con Java 11, Spring Boot 2.7.10 ModelMapper 3.1.1 tengo lo siguiente:

Categoria

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categorías")

public class Categoria implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7322199606479196556L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String nombre;
private EstadoCategoria estado;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoria", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<SubCategoria> subCategorias = new ArrayList<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public EstadoCategoria getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(EstadoCategoria estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}
}
```

EstadoCategoria

```
public enum EstadoCategoria {
ACTIVO(1),
INACTIVO(0);

private final int valor;

EstadoCategoria(int valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

public int getValor() {
    return valor;
}
}
```

CategoriaDto

```
public class CategoriaDto {
private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "El nombre no puede estar vacío")
@NotEmpty(message = "El nombre no puede estar vacío")
@NotNull
private String nombre;

@NotNull
private Integer estado;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Integer getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Integer estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}
}
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
private ISdCategoria sdCategoria;

@Autowired
private GenericModelMapper modelMapper;

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<CategoriaDto>> GetAllAsync() {
    var categorías = sdCategoria.GetAllAsync();

    List<CategoriaDto> categoriasDto = modelMapper.mapToListCategoriaDto(categorias);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(categoriasDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Lo que tengo implementado en `GenericModelMapper` es lo siguiente:

```
@Component
public class GenericModelMapper {
@Autowired
private ModelMapper mapper;

public Categoria mapToCategoria(CategoriaDto categoriaDto) {
    return mapper.map(categoriaDto, Categoria.class);
}

public CategoriaDto mapToCategoriaDto(Categoria categoria) {
    return mapper.map(categoria, CategoriaDto.class);
}

public List<CategoriaDto> mapToListCategoriaDto(List<Categoria> categorias) {
    return categorias.stream()
            .map(categoria -> {
                CategoriaDto categoriaDto = new CategoriaDto();
                mapper.createTypeMap(categoria, CategoriaDto.class)
                        .addMapping(src -> src.getEstado().ordinal(), CategoriaDto::setEstado);
                mapper.map(categoria, categoriaDto);
                return categoriaDto;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
}
```

Tengo problemas en `mapToListCategoriaDto` me da el siguiente error:

```
{
"exception": "ErrorsException",
"message": null,
"path": "/api/categorías"
}
```

No llega a entrar al méodo `mapToListCategoriaDto` desde esta linea lanza la excepción `List<CategoriaDto> categoriasDto = modelMapper.mapToListCategoriaDto(categorias);`Como lo puedo soluciona.

De antemano gracias...

Comment: ErrorsException es una excepción creada por ti?

Comment: @PabloLozano `ErrorsException` es creado por mi

Comment: Pues entonces tienes que ver dónde lanzas esa excepción, el código que has mostrado no incluye ningún try-catch o throw

Comment: Con propósitos de prueba te sugiero desactivar el mecanismo por el cual creas la excepción y ver la traza del error. ¿Puede ser que `sdCategoria.GetAllAsync()` devuelva nulo?